# How can I compare two sets of data in linq and return the common data?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two `IList<string>` a and b. I want to find out what strings are in both a and b using LINQ.

Comment: Your question and title appear to contradict each other. Do you want the items that are in both, or do you want the differences?

Comment: sorry only the one that are in both :)

Comment: I know I am noob to linq but did the question have to voted down??

Comment: Don't worry about it - if you edit your question so that the title and the actual question agree with one another, people should remove their downvotes :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`Intersect`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary):

> Produces the set intersection of two sequences.

```
a.Intersect(b)
```

Example usage:

```
IList<string> a = new List<string> { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
IList<string> b = new List<string> { "baz", "bar", "qux" };

var stringsInBoth = a.Intersect(b);

foreach (string s in stringsInBoth)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Output:

```
bar
baz
```